# WebGL, negative scale normal

Tags: javascript, webgl

I try to render lights on some models.
All models have some uniques options (scale, position, rotation). I create a matrix with all this options and change all model's vertices from this matrix.

I have a big problem when the model has a negative scale, the normal is reversed and don't looks like it should.

[image]

Here the code I use:

```
vec3.calcNormal = function( a, b, c, dest ) {
    var v1 = dest || vec3.create(), v2 = vec3.create();
    vec3.subtract( c, b, v1 );
    vec3.subtract( a, b, v2 );
    vec3.cross( v1, v2 );
    return vec3.normalize(v1);
};
```

---

```
// Apply matrix on vertices
size  = vertices.length;
vert  = new Array(size);
for( i=0; i<size; ++i ) {
    vert[i] = vec3.create();
    mat4.multiplyVec3(  matrix, vertices[i],  vert[i] );
}


// Generate face normals
face_normal    = new Array(faces.length);
for ( i=0, count=faces.length; i<count; ++i ) {
    face           = faces[i];
    face_normal[i] = vec3.create();

    vec3.calcNormal(
        vert[ face.vertidx[0] ],
        vert[ face.vertidx[1] ],
        vert[ face.vertidx[2] ],
        face_normal[i]
    );
}
```

Does someone know how to fix this problem ?
I tried to scale back the normal or don't scale it at all, but It didn't work.

**Fixed with:**

```
// Get normal matrix
mat3.transpose( mat4.toInverseMat3(matrix), normalMat );

// Apply matrix on vertices
size  = vertices.length;
vert  = new Array(size);
for( i=0; i<size; ++i ) {
    vert[i] = vec3.create();
    mat4.multiplyVec3(  matrix, vertices[i],  vert[i] );
}


// Generate face normals
face_normal    = new Array(faces.length);
for ( i=0, count=faces.length; i<count; ++i ) {
    face           = faces[i];
    face_normal[i] = vec3.create();

    vec3.calcNormal(
        vertices[ face.vertidx[0] ],
        vertices[ face.vertidx[1] ],
        vertices[ face.vertidx[2] ],
        face_normal[i]
    );

    mat3.multiplyVec3( normalMat, face_normal[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative scale value will flip your geometry: [demo](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/webgl_transforms/webgl/webgl-2d-geometry-scale.html) From [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/webgl_transforms/#toc-scale). If you need to shrink it you should use fraction value.

Comment: Yeah I know that negative scale value flip the geometry. What I want is just to find a way on how to generate appropriate normal in this case.

Comment: IF geometry getting flipped you allso need to flip normals.  For normal transformation you need separate matrix read this http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/the-normal-matrix/

Comment: Thank you JAre, it works ! So basically inverse the matrix and transpose it and finally multiply all normals with it :)